# Install java,ide and create a sample web application

Tags: java, macos

I recently received a macbook pro.
I wanted to to learn java,jsp and develop some sample web applications in my local machine.
Can anyone provide me a specific link where I can perform the following on my Mac Os to get started:

- Install Java
- Install an IDE.
- set up tomcat
- Tutorial for creating learning sample program that contains java,jsp
  connect to a local db and test it out in my local web browser.

I know there are lot of different instructions in the web, i would appreciate if some of the experts here point me to the best way to get started .

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) may be better suited for this question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Will already be installed on a mac
2. I would suggest either [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) as two examples of good Java IDEs.  Both have very good support for developing web applications in Java.  The IDE question is probably never ending, so it's really a case of what works for you.
3. For Tomcat you can't beat [these](http://tomcat.apache.org/) instructions.
4. Each framework has its own instructions. Perhaps start with Spring or Play! for java

Comment: Will Java come preinstalled on OS X? I didn't think so.

Comment: @Whymarrh is right Java doesn't come by default on new Macs, but running `java` from terminal gives a prompt to install JavaSE 6. (But if you're installing java, you could just go to Oracle and download the Java 7 JDK, or go to Apple and get the Apple Developer Tools and the Java 6 JDK.

Comment: Apologies - you're right!  I'm on an older version of OSX and didn't know that http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml#getjava.  @Lion - edited with less bias.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help..though 4 negative votes was not what i expected. Maybe it was a stupid question. i just wanted some tips for java beginner like me.